# vscode snippet variables: how to get content from output of command line program

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Up until now, I have a number of vscode snippet templates where I'm using the built-in [`$UUID` variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables) to replace `$UUID` placeholders with random UUIDs like `3edbdc43-10b9-405e-9a9a-6e02a19bb408` when the snippet is inserted into any code.

I've now written my own CLI program `my_custom_uuid_generator.exe` which generates UUIDs using my own special custom format, and just prints the generated UUID string to `STDOUT`.

How can I create a different snippet variable similar to `$UUID`, but which instead:

1. runs my `my_custom_uuid_generator.exe`
2. captures the output from it
3. uses that in place of the placeholder

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a great way to do this right now (or any way at all, though I'd be happy to be wrong). This would probably require a combination of two currently pending feature-requests to go through:

- [Execute functions during snippet expansion #10561](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10561) (to enable calling a function that runs a command in a terminal, and then returns the result)
- [Expose shell integration command knowledge to extensions #145234](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/145234) (to be able to write an extension that can run a command in the terminal and be able to get the result)

I suggest that you give those issue tickets a thumbs up to show support for them. You can also subscribe to them to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".